# Fixed Position <div> Extends Beyond Bottom of Page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a `<div>` which is basically a shopping cart which I want to have fixed to the right as the user scrolls through content.  I'm using Bootstrap and have this...

```
<div id="my_order" class="well order_panel affix">
  stuff
</div>
```

The problem is that if `.stuff` gets tall, the height of `<div id="my_order">` gets to the point where the bottom of it is off the bottom of the page of the browser window.  Like this...

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8">some stuff</div>
<div id="my_order" class="col-md-4 well order_panel affix">
      begin
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      I can't see this!!!
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Set 100vh on the height and overflow-y:scoll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example using max-height:100vh. I've removed the wrapping .row as it adds extra padding to the parent div which causes the horizontal scrollbar, which hides the last line of text beneath.

```css
.wrap{
position:relative;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

.order_panel{
  position:fixed;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  max-height:100vh;
  overflow-y:auto;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  z-index:10;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="col-md-8">some stuff</div>
  <div id="my_order" class="col-md-4 well order_panel affix">
      begin
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      I can't see this!!!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Almost there, except of `100vh` shall go to `max-height:100vh;` really
and  `overflow-y:auto;` would be better.

Comment: @c-smile Thanks for that, max-height might be more appropriate to the question and overflow auto is a bit less ugly, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Yet not clear what top/right are doing there without position defined.

Comment: @c-smile I've added the fixed to the child and relative to the parent, so it should be a bit more coherent now.

Comment: I only ended up using part of this answer (and part of the answer from @Johannes below).  The `overflow-y: auto;` was crucial.

Comment: @gtilflm glad you sorted it out!

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow-y: scroll;` on it, plus limit its height to a little bit less than the container/window height, like `height: calc(100% - 2em);`, or `height: calc(100vh - 2em);`, if the percentage doesn't work. (depends on the height settings of the container element). And adjust/fine-tune the `1.8em` in the `calc` part as you need it.

```css
#my_order {
  max-height: calc(100% - 1.8em);
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">some stuff</div>
  <div id="my_order" class="col-md-4 well order_panel affix">
    begin
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br> I can't see this!!!
  </div>
</div>
```